# How to map one array element which is separated by newlines into a new array with multiple elements

Tags: bash, nautilus, array, nemo

I select 4 files in Nemo in the path `/home/myUsername/.local/share/nemo/scripts/Folder with spaces/`. Nemo stores the file paths in the environment variable `NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS`.

(As you can see in the answer from `glenn jackman` below, `NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` contains a newline-separated list of file paths.)

Why is "Yeah!" not printed after every file path line? How can I achieve that? (This question is maybe irritating, because I initially thought this list of file paths is an array, which it is obviously not.)

**SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "${NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
    echo "Yeah!"
done
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/home/myUsername/.local/share/nemo/scripts/Folder with spaces/script1
/home/myUsername/.local/share/nemo/scripts/Folder with spaces/script2
/home/myUsername/.local/share/nemo/scripts/Folder with spaces/script3
/home/myUsername/.local/share/nemo/scripts/Folder with spaces/script4

Yeah!
```

Comment: Because your array only contains one element. Try `echo "${#NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS[@]}"` to see how many elements are in the array. Please show how you populate that array.

Comment: Nice job quoting all your variables. Too often we don't see that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming:

- the environment variable `$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` is somehow magically set for you by nemo, and
- it contains a newline-separated list of filenames,

you can parse it out into a bash array like this:

```
$ NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS="file one
file two
file three"

$ mapfile -t files <<<"$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"

$ echo ${#files[@]}
3

$ printf ">>%s\n" "${files[@]}"
>>file one
>>file two
>>file three
```

`mapfile` is a bash builtin command that reads standard input, splits on newlines and stores the lines in the named array.

This breaks if any of your filenames contain newlines (which is a legal filename character).